# DataFrame pairs of columns division

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and want to get divisions of pairs of columns like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a1': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 1000),
    'a2': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 1000),
    'b1': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 1000),
    'b2': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 1000),
    'c1': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 1000),
    'c2': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 1000),
})
df['a'] = df['a2'] / df['a1']
df['b'] = df['b2'] / df['b1']
df['c'] = df['c2'] / df['c1']
```

I want to combine the last three lines into one like:

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c']] = df[['a2', 'b2', 'c2']] / df[['a1', 'b1', 'c1']]
```

but I only get an error of `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`. If I just simply `print(df[['a2', 'b2', 'c2']] / df[['a1', 'b1', 'c1']])`, I will only get a DataFrame with `NaN`s of shape (1000, 6).

==== Edit

Now I know why my original one-line code doesn't work. Actually, the arithmetic operations of two DataFrames will be conducted between the columns with same labels, while those columns without same label in another DataFrame will generate NaNs. The result DataFrame will have the union() of the columns of the two operating DataFrames. That's why my original solution will give an `ValueError` and the div will generate `NaN`s.

Following example will be helpful to explain:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4], 'C':[5,6], 'D':[8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[11,12], 'B':[13,14], 'C':[15,16], 'D':[18,19]})
df1[['A', 'B']] / df2[['A', 'B']]
Out[130]: 
          A         B
0  0.090909  0.230769
1  0.166667  0.285714

df1[['A', 'B']] / df2[['C', 'D']]
Out[131]: 
    A   B   C   D
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN

df1[['A', 'B']] + df2[['A', 'C']]
Out[132]: 
    A   B   C
0  12 NaN NaN
1  14 NaN NaN
```

Comment: Convert into a multiindex and do the division

Comment: `df[['a','b','c']] = df[['a2', 'b2', 'c2']] / df[['a1', 'b1', 'c1']].to_numpy()` your columns don't match.

Comment: Also provide small reproducible data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c']] = df[['a2', 'b2', 'c2']].values / df[['a1', 'b1', 'c1']].values
```

`OUTPUT`

```
      a1   a2   b1   b2   c1   c2          a         b         c
0    864  214  551  761  174  111   0.247685  1.381125  0.637931
1    820  971  379   79  190  587   1.184146  0.208443  3.089474
2    305  154  519  378  567  186   0.504918  0.728324  0.328042
3     51  505  303  417  959  326   9.901961  1.376238  0.339937
4     84  531  625  899  248  905   6.321429  1.438400  3.649194
..   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...        ...       ...       ...
995  302  695  790  777  896  975   2.301325  0.983544  1.088170
996   24  308  462  316  388  784  12.833333  0.683983  2.020619
997  135  286  359  752  282  283   2.118519  2.094708  1.003546
998  695   45  832  936  811  404   0.064748  1.125000  0.498150
999  809  454  971  335  366  884   0.561187  0.345005  2.415301
```

Comment: Imagine u have lots of columns, how do you keep track of d pairs

Comment: @Muhammad Hassan, that is a great solution. Can you explain why your solution works, while mine does not? Thanks.

Comment: @Cuteufo I also expected `df.div(other)` to work, as in the documentation it says `other` can be a dataframe. Don't have a concrete answer for why `df.div` does not work here. In my solution however we are dividing two numpy arrays which is equivalent to `np.divide(array_1, array_2)` or in our case `np.divide(df[['a2', 'b2', 'c2']].values, df[['a1', 'b1', 'c1']].values)`

Comment: @sammywemmy good point but I don't think thats something of concern for OP here. Moreover, can you please elaborate on your comment above `Convert into a multiindex and do the division`. Why do we need multiindex?

Comment: I’ll add a concrete example to explain the usefulness of multiindex in this case.

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks, that will be great.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following as simple workaround:

```py
df['a'], df['b'], df['c'] = (df['a2'] / df['a1'], df['b2'] / df['b1'], df['c2'] / df['c1'])
```

Although I think that using the [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method would make your code much more readable:

```py
df.assign(a=lambda x: x['a2'] / x['a1'], 
          b=lambda x: x['b2'] / x['b1'], 
          c=lambda x: x['c2'] / x['c1'])
```

Answer (score 1):

MultiIndex comes in handy here, since Pandas is always aligned first on the index(columns is an index as well) before any computations.

Using sample data below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a_1':range(2,10,2),
            'a_2': range(4, 20, 4),
           'b_1': range(3, 15,3),
           'b_2': range(6,30,6),
           'c_1': range(5, 25, 5),
           'c_2': range(10, 50, 10)})

df
   a_1  a_2  b_1  b_2  c_1  c_2
0    2    4    3    6    5   10
1    4    8    6   12   10   20
2    6   12    9   18   15   30
3    8   16   12   24   20   40
```

split the columns into a MultiIndex:

```py
temp = df.copy()
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split('_', expand = True).swaplevel()

temp

 1   2   1   2   1   2
   a   a   b   b   c   c
0  2   4   3   6   5  10
1  4   8   6  12  10  20
2  6  12   9  18  15  30
3  8  16  12  24  20  40
```

In this form, you can simply select `2` divided by `1`:

```py
df['a','b','c']] = temp['2'] / temp['1']
```

This gives the same values as :

```py
df[['a_2', 'b_2', 'c_2']].values / df[['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']].values
```

Imagine however, that you have lots of columns, you do not need to worry about the pairing, as the MultiIndex form takes care of that, with Pandas doing the alignment before computation.

Numpy is going to be faster - @MuhammadHassan's answer fits nicely; this is just to show how MultiIndex has its place and its uses in the right circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped, but I'm still unable to understand why `df[['a_2', 'b_2', 'c_2']].div(df[['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']])` does not work.

Comment: I think I have understood now what you are trying to say. If we consider a simple dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4], 'C':[5,6], 'D':[8,9]})` then this `df[['A', 'B']].div(df[['C', 'D']].rename(columns={'C':'A', 'D':'B'}))` produce the expected result. But simply doing this `df[['A', 'B']].div(df[['C', 'D']])` produces nans. Thanks again for this explanation

Comment: I don't know if this is what you mean, but by reading your comments I figured out the reason why my solution in original post won't work. I will put my understanding with example in the question. Thanks @MuhammadHassan and @ sammywemmy.